# AWS Athena only shows 99 rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv

I'm analyzing a CSV with 60K+ rows and AWS Athena only shows 99 rows and doesn't show the same 99 rows consistently.

I'm getting what appears to be a random group of rows each time.

I'm running this query:

```sql
SELECT city, AVG(value),
         from_iso8601_date('2018-10-09')
FROM openaq
WHERE country = 'US'
GROUP BY  city;
```

How do I get everything to come back?

Comment: To clarify, you are running the query in the Athena management console? If you scroll to the bottom of the result set, does it load the next 100 records for you? If not, can you try it with a different browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc)? The result set does a "lazy load" and only loads more records if you go to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Can you download the result and confirm if you are able to see all the rows that you want to?

Comment: Thank you for the "lazy load" information.  With that, I was able to see more results. And I was able to download results.  Turns out some of the data didn't load initially.

Comment: Beyond that, for some reason with the size of the data, I'm getting back inconsistent results.  The same query will return different values.